# Does not Including the Version of a Dll Differ From Including It and Setting SpecificVersion to False?

Tags: c#, dll, msbuild, visual-studio-2013

Given these two csProj reference definitions for the AjaxControlToolKit:

```xml
<Reference Include="AjaxControlToolkit, Version=4.1.7.1213, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <HintPath>..\packages\AjaxControlToolkit.7.1213\lib\40\AjaxControlToolkit.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>

<Reference Include="AjaxControlToolkit">
  <HintPath>..\packages\AjaxControlToolkit.7.1213\lib\40\AjaxControlToolkit.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Does does this change how VS finds dll, and can it potentially change what dll is referenced?

Are there any potential effects this could have at runtime, when the code has been deployed?

Comment: Hmm, no, not if the DLL is stored in a subdirectory named "AjaxControlToolkit.7.1213".  Making the build and revision numbers part of the storage location ought the reduce the risk of getting the wrong one exceedingly low.

Comment: @HansPassant so you're saying, as long as the Hint Path points to the version specified in the Include attribute, there really isn't a difference?  And it also therefore, doesn't have an affect on Runtime?

Comment: HintPath explicitly tells the compiler what reference DLL file to use.  What DLL is used at runtime depends on how you deploy.  The normal way is to also have the Copy Local property set to True so you get a copy of the reference assembly in the build directory.  Which you then deploy along with the project build result so you always run with the version that you compiled against.  No accidents that way.